# Transposing a DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a dataframe in Python that consists of one row of time series data. Every column is a date with a median sales price but I would like to switch this from wide to long. Essentially, I want to have two columns: `Date` and `Median Sale Price` but I'm not sure how to do this. There are 523 columns of dates.

I used `.to_dict()` to get a sample of the data:

```
{'2012-01-07': {0: 166250.0},
 '2012-01-14': {0: 163750.0},
 '2012-01-21': {0: 161875.0},
 '2012-01-28': {0: 160600.0},
 '2012-02-04': {0: 160100.0},
 '2012-02-11': {0: 158850.0},
 '2012-02-18': {0: 158537.0},
 '2012-02-25': {0: 158537.0},
 '2012-03-03': {0: 159787.0},
 '2012-03-10': {0: 161757.0},
 '2012-03-17': {0: 163194.0}}
```

Comment: without a sample, it's hard to say what's an appropriate solution

Comment: use `df.T` for the transposition but not sure how you want Median calculated.  You need more detail

Comment: @enke I've added a sample of the data to the question

Comment: @piRSquared sorry I wasn't clear, the price listed in the dataset is the median sales price so no calculation is needed

Comment: I think this should work for you: `df.T.reset_index()`